Remove blob from azure storage account through bicep but exlude blob from develop branch
We set up a storage account and azure storage account life cycle management policies for removing the blobs that are older than 100days and so on. What we noticed that this policy will remove all blobs including the one from develop branch. What we are trying to achieve is that we create such policy so that we exculde the blob from develop branch but remove all other blob files from a container. Can't find any relevant examples to do this. Yes, the azure life cycle management has prefixMatch property for filtering purposes but we cannot use negation rules here. Does anybody have better ideas how to achieve it and some good examples if possible.
Here is our bicep examples of life cycle management rules looks like currently:
resource storageAccountManagementPolicies 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies@2023-01-01'{
  name: 'Storage Account Name'
  properties: {
    policy: {
      rules: [
        {
          enabled: true
          name: 'Delete blobs'
          type: 'Lifecycle'
          definition: {
            actions: {
              baseBlob: {
                delete: {
                  daysAfterCreationGreaterThan: 100
                }
              }
            }
            filters: {
              blobTypes: [
                'blockBlob'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



Remove blob from azure storage account through bicep but exlude blob from develop branch

According to this MS-Q&A by Ramya Harinarthini_MSFT.
In Azure blob storage lifecycle management policy, there is no feature to exclude specific folder. so, it is not possible to do with azure blob life cycle policy.
The prefixMatch supports only positive matchs. Alternatively, you can use python code to delete the blob under specific days with exclude the specific folder.
Code:
import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage account name>;AccountKey=<accountkey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")

# Define the container and the "test" prefix to exclude
container_name = "data"
excluded_prefix = "test/"
days_threshold = 5


container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    if blob.name.startswith(excluded_prefix):
        continue
    
    blob_creation_date = blob.creation_time
    blob_age = (datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - blob_creation_date).days

    if blob_age > days_threshold:
        print(f"Deleting blob: {blob.name}")
        container_client.delete_blob(blob.name)

The above code will exclude the test folder and delete the blobs which is older than 5 days for testing purpose.
Output:
Deleting blob: README.txt
Deleting blob: backup-2022-11-15-1430.zip.zip
Deleting blob: demo.pdf
Deleting blob: demo326.cer
Deleting blob: demo326.cer.thumbprint.txt
Deleting blob: demo326.key.txt
Deleting blob: demo326.pfx
Deleting blob: example.csv


You can use Azure Automation  or Azure function to run Python scripts with automation process.
